# interp1(x,y,xq) in Matlab when x,xq: numeric array, and y: string array

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Is there a way for using `interp1` function as `interp1(x,y,xq)` when `x,xq`: are  numeric arrays, and `y`: is a string array?

Or can you think of an equivalent vectorial way for this?

I do not want to convert to table and use `tablelookup` though.

Example:

```
x = [1, 3, 4, 7, 8];
y = ["A", "A", "B", "C", "C"];
xq = [2.5, 5, 6.7];
```

Comment: `interp1` is a *mathematical* function. How would you even define it in terms of a string? Does `y` contain numbers? At least I hope so, and in that case you can use `str2double(y)`, if those are not numbers, please elaborate on you you'd define string-based interpolation.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain an [mcve], thus give sample inputs of `x`, `xq` and `y`, and give sample output as to how you want this to look.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? What is `yq` for `xq=6.7`? It is somewhere in between "B" and "C", closer to "C". What is there?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: it can be any fillmissing strategy, as nearest, previous, next. Check the below answer :)

Comment: But that is not interpolation... at least not conceptually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want some kind of nearest-neighbor or ordered imputation.  In that case, you can use `interp1` but interpolate onto the *indices* of the source array, then use the result to index into the source values.

```
>> x = [1 3 4 7 8];
>> y = ["hi" "hello" "bonjour" "hallo" "hola"];
>> xq = [2 5 6];
>> yq = y(interp1(x,1:length(x),xq,'nearest'))
yq = 
  1×3 string array
    "hello"    "bonjour"    "hallo"
```